# ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction would cause overdraft'} How to Solve this?

Tags: python, ethereum, blockchain, web3js

```
 def execute_trade(pair_contract, token0_address, token1_address, token0_price_usdt, token1_price_usdt, token0_symbol, token1_symbol, exchange_name,
                  token0_price_1, token1_price_1, token0_symbol_1, token1_symbol_1, exchange_name_1, price_ratio_1, price_percentage_1):
    # INVEST ----------------->"the amount of USDT to use for trading"
    pdb.set_trace()
    usdt_amount = 10  # Adjust the amount as per your preference

    # Calculate the token amounts to buy and sell
    token0_amount = usdt_amount / token0_price_usdt
    token1_amount = usdt_amount / token1_price_usdt

    # Convert token amounts to uint256
    token0_amount_uint = Web3.to_wei(token0_amount, 'ether')
    token1_amount_uint = Web3.to_wei(token1_amount, 'ether')

    # Approve the pair contract to spend USDT from your account
    usdt_contract = web3M.eth.contract(address='0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7', abi=usdt_abi)
    nonce = web3M.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address)+1
    approve_tx = usdt_contract.functions.approve(pair_contract.address, usdt_amount).build_transaction({
        'from': account_address,
        'gas':  200000,
        'gasPrice': web3M.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
        'chainId': 1 # Replace with the actual chain ID
    })
    signed_approve_tx = web3M.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_tx, private_key=private_key)
    approve_tx_hash = None
    try:
     if signed_approve_tx.rawTransaction:
        approve_tx_hash = web3M.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_approve_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(f"Approve transaction sent. Transaction Hash: {web3M.to_hex(approve_tx_hash)}")
     else:
        print("Error: The raw transaction is None. Please check the signing process.")
        return
    except ValueError as e:
     if "already known" in str(e):
        print("Transaction already known. Skipping approval.")
     else:
        print("Error sending approve transaction:", e)
        return

# Add a delay before checking the transaction receipt
    time.sleep(40)

    while True:
     try:
        if approve_tx_hash:
            receipt = web3M.eth.get_transaction(approve_tx_hash)
            if receipt:
                print("Transaction receipt found.")
                break
        else:
         print("Error: The transaction hash is None. Skipping receipt retrieval.")
         break
     except ValueError as e:
        print("Error retrieving transaction receipt:", e)
        break
     except Exception as e:
        print("Unexpected error occurred while retrieving transaction receipt:", e)
        break
    print("Approve transaction mined.")

    # Buy token on the exchange with the lowest token price
    if token0_price_usdt <= token1_price_usdt:
        buy_token_address = token0_address
        buy_token_amount = token0_amount_uint
        min_token_price = token0_price_usdt
    else:
        buy_token_address = token1_address
        buy_token_amount = token1_amount_uint
        min_token_price = token1_price_usdt

    # Check if the price conditions for the first exchange are met
    if token0_price_usdt == token0_price and token1_price_usdt == token1_price:
        nonce = web3M.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address) + 1
        
        # Perform the trade on the first exchange
        buy_tx = pair_contract.functions.swap(buy_token_amount, 0, buy_token_address, b'').build_transaction({
            'from': account_address,
            'gas':  200000,
            'gasPrice': web3M.to_wei('100', 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            'chainId': 1# Replace with the actual chain ID
        })
        signed_buy_tx = web3M.eth.account.sign_transaction(buy_tx, private_key=private_key)
        buy_tx_hash = web3M.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_buy_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(f"Buy transaction sent. Transaction Hash: {web3M.to_hex(buy_tx_hash)}")
        time.sleep(60)

        max_retries = 3
        retry_interval = 10  # seconds
        retry_count = 0
        # Wait for the buy transaction to be mined
        while retry_count < max_retries:
            try:
                receipt = web3M.eth.get_transaction_receipt(buy_tx_hash)
                if receipt is not None:
                    break
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            retry_count += 1
            print(f"Fetching..{retry_count}/{max_retries} - Waiting for transaction to be mined...")
            time.sleep(retry_interval)
        if receipt is not None:
         print("Buy transaction mined.")
        else:
         print("Buy transaction not mined after maximum retries.")

    # Check if the price conditions for the second exchange are met
    elif token0_price_usdt == token0_price_1 and token1_price_usdt == token1_price_1:
        nonce = web3M.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address) + 1
        
        # Perform the trade on the second exchang
        buy_tx = pair_contract.functions.swap(buy_token_amount, 0, buy_token_address, b'').build_transaction({
            'from': account_address,
            'gas':  200000,
            'gasPrice': web3M.to_wei('60', 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            'chainId': 1# Replace with the actual chain ID
        })
        signed_buy_tx = web3M.eth.account.sign_transaction(buy_tx, private_key=private_key)
        buy_tx_hash = web3M.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_buy_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(f"Buy transaction sent. Transaction Hash: {web3M.to_hex(buy_tx_hash)}")
        time.sleep(60)

        # Wait for the buy transaction to be mined with retry
        max_retries = 3
        retry_interval = 10  # seconds
        retry_count = 0
        # Wait for the buy transaction to be mined
        while retry_count < max_retries:
            try:
                receipt = web3M.eth.get_transaction_receipt(buy_tx_hash)
                if receipt is not None:
                    break
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            retry_count += 1
            print(f"Fetching.. {retry_count}/{max_retries} - Waiting for transaction to be mined...")
            time.sleep(retry_interval)
            
        if receipt is not None:
         print("Buy transaction mined.")
        else:
         print("Buy transaction not mined after maximum retries.")

    # Sell token on the exchange with the highest token price
    if token0_price_usdt >= token1_price_usdt:
        sell_token_address = token0_address
        sell_token_amount = token0_amount
        max_token_price = token0_price_usdt
    else:
        sell_token_address = token1_address
        sell_token_amount = token1_amount
        max_token_price = token1_price_usdt

    # Check if the price conditions for the first exchange are met
    if token0_price_usdt == token0_price and token1_price_usdt == token1_price:
        nonce = web3M.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address)
        
        # Perform the trade on the first exchange
        sell_tx = pair_contract.functions.swap(token0_amount_uint, 0, sell_token_address, to_bytes(text='')).build_transaction({
            'from': account_address,
            'gas':  200000,
            'gasPrice': web3M.to_wei('60', 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            'chainId': 1# Replace with the actual chain ID
        })
        signed_sell_tx = web3M.eth.account.sign_transaction(sell_tx, private_key=private_key)
        sell_tx_hash = web3M.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_sell_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(f"Sell transaction sent. Transaction Hash: {web3M.to_hex(sell_tx_hash)}")
        time.sleep(60)

        # Wait for the buy transaction to be mined with retry
        max_retries = 3
        retry_interval = 10  # seconds
        retry_count = 0
        # Wait for the sell transaction to be mined
        while retry_count < max_retries:
            try:
                receipt = web3M.eth.get_transaction_receipt(sell_tx_hash)
                if receipt is not None:
                    break
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            retry_count += 1
            print(f"Fetching.. {retry_count}/{max_retries} - Waiting for transaction to be mined...")
            time.sleep(retry_interval)
        if receipt is not None:
          print("Buy transaction mined.")
        else:
         print("Buy transaction not mined after maximum retries.")

    # Check if the price conditions for the second exchange are met
    elif token0_price_usdt == token0_price_1 and token1_price_usdt == token1_price_1:
        # Retrieve the transaction count for the sender's address
        nonce = web3M.eth.get_transaction_count(account_address)
        
        # Perform the trade on the second exchange
        sell_tx = pair_contract.functions.swap(sell_token_amount, 0, sell_token_address, b'').build_transaction({
            'from': account_address,
            'gas':  200000,
            'gasPrice': web3M.to_wei('60', 'gwei'),
            'nonce': nonce,
            'chainId': 1 # Replace with the actual chain ID
        })
        signed_sell_tx = web3M.eth.account.sign_transaction(sell_tx, private_key=private_key)
        sell_tx_hash = web3M.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_sell_tx.rawTransaction)
        print(f"Sell transaction sent. Transaction Hash: {web3M.to_hex(sell_tx_hash)}")
        time.sleep(60)

        # Wait for the buy transaction to be mined with retry
        max_retries = 3
        retry_interval = 10  # seconds
        retry_count = 0
        # Wait for the sell transaction to be mined
        while retry_count < max_retries:
            try:
                receipt = web3M.eth.get_transaction_receipt(sell_tx_hash)
                if receipt is not None:
                    break
            except TransactionNotFound:
                pass
            retry_count += 1
            print(f"Fetching.. {retry_count}/{max_retries} - Waiting for transaction to be mined...")
            time.sleep(retry_interval)
        if receipt is not None:
         print("Buy transaction mined.")
        else:
         print("Buy transaction not mined after maximum retries.")

    else:
        # No suitable exchange found
        print("No suitable exchange found for the specified price conditions.")

    # Print the trade details
    print(f"Buy {buy_token_amount:.6f} {token0_symbol if token0_symbol != 'USDT' else token1_symbol} for {usdt_amount:.2f} USDT at {min_token_price:.6f} USDT/{token0_symbol if token0_symbol != 'USDT' else token1_symbol}")
    print(f"Sell {sell_token_amount:.6f} {token0_symbol if token0_symbol != 'USDT' else token1_symbol} for {usdt_amount:.2f} USDT at {max_token_price:.6f} USDT/{token0_symbol if token0_symbol != 'USDT' else token1_symbol}")
```

This code is working fine on test net but when running it on main net it gives error: `“ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced'}” .So I had also seen its solution on the internet, to increase the gas price or to increase the nonce.But the code  started showing these error{‘code': -32000, 'message': 'exceeds block gas limit’}.So I went back to just reducing the gas price but that same  error started coming back .“ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'replacement transaction underpriced’}”. i solved all this error but after incresing gwei it giving me new error - ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'transaction would cause overdraft'}`

i want to expect approve transaction buy and sell

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall the metamask wallet or add new wallet extensions in new browser window then transfer the tokens from old to new wallet and use the private key of new wallet to deployed the contract.
It will work, I tried it.